# How to tell where my JavaScript click event is being canceled

Tags: javascript, debugging, event-handling, cancellation

I'm working on a Shopify project and am not the original developer, who is unavailable, along with an un-minified version of the javascript file included on every page.

The original site has a page displaying a grid of employee headshots. I have been tasked with enhancing by making it such that each headshot has an overlay that displays some additional info and that clicking on either the headshot image OR the overlay (and its contents) will take some additional action.

Each grid item (headshot) essentially looks like this:

```
<div class="wrap">
  <img src="PATH_TO_IMG">
  <div class="info">Danny Testeroni</div>
</div>
```

and my event listener/handler looks like this:

```
const $item = document.querySelector('.wrap');
$item.addEventListener('click', (e) => {
  console.log(e.target);
});
```

All works as expected.

Clicking anywhere within the grid item, `console.log`s the image **UNLESS** you click anywhere on the overlay, in which case, it `console.log`s the overlay container. This is what I need.

However when I add this to the actual Shopify template (in which this global JavaScript file gets included), i get different results.

Clicking anywhere within the grid item, `console.log`s the image **UNLESS** you click anywhere on the overlay, in which case, it `console.log`s NOTHING.

The only thing I can conclude is that something in the global JavaScript file is canceling the click event at the `<img>` so it never makes it to the overlay. Is this the case? If so, is there any way to tell where this is happening and possibly overriding it with my new script? And if not, any ideas why clicks on the overlay may not be registering in the actual Shop as opposed to my bare bones prototype, which can be seen in [this Codepen](https://codepen.io/daveh0/pen/mdpPZeK)?

Comment: Elements further up the DOM tree are possibly using click event capture to implement event delegation. The reported end result could be explained by the captured event handler processing a click if its target is an employee headshot (image element) but cancelling the event no matter whether it is or isn't. You might be able to learn more from DOM inspector tools in the browser or source code - it's not something I can check from the post.

Comment: "*Is this the case?*" - maybe yes, there might be a `event.stopPropagation()` in another handler. But maybe the thing rendering the "overlay" puts it elsewhere in the dom, not as a child of the wrapper? You'll need to show us that script responsible for the overlays. "*Is there any way to tell where this is happening?*" - you can add a breakpoint on click events and then step through each handler. "*…possibly overriding it with my new script?*" - no. You need to change the original script.

Comment: @Bergi - so at the ned of the day, since the only other script running on my page is this other, global, minified file, there's not much use trying to figure out which line of code is preventing further propagation, as without bing able to edit that file (un-minified), i'll have to create a new click listener/handler for the overlay regardless - is that accurate?

Comment: @Bergi - "But maybe the thing rendering the "overlay" puts it elsewhere in the dom" - there is no script - it's static HTML that renders the overlay... just as in my example... so as far as know, it is a child of the wrapper.

Comment: In the barbers page linked in your comment, open the inspector tool and click on the event icon next to the HTML tag in source (in Firefox at least). This lists global event listeners in order of event name, and shows a capturing click handler being added at "https:www.fellowbarber.com/pages/barbers:65:679". This is a minified file, but looking at the the un-minified handler code **might or might not** be useful. Good luck with your problem solving.

Comment: @traktor - super-helpful - I've been wondering how to do that for a while and never had too much cause until now. From what I can tell in the original script, it looks like someone (probably the original developer) did have a delegated listener on each image that stops the propagation right at the image... perhaps they were starting to do the enhancements I'm currently working on. Anyway, I guess I just need to place my listener/handler after the original so that propagation up to the overlay can occur.

Answer (score -1):

You can remove the arrow function on your addEventListener handle and use this, to reference the element it was attached to

```js
const $item = document.querySelector('.wrap');
$item.addEventListener('click', function(e) {
  console.log(this);
})
```

```html
<div class="wrap">
  <img src="https://cdn.shopify.com/s/files/1/0598/3089/4765/articles/barber-culture_x700.png?v=1646319227">
  <div class="info">Danny Testeroni</div>
</div>
```

Comment: unfortunately, in the context of the entire Shop (with the global JavaScript I believe to be the culprit here), replacing the arrow function with a 'regular" function produces the same end result... clicking on the overlay does not register a click event.

Comment: The problem is not that `e.target` (or `e.currentTarget`, which would the the `this` argument) is undefined, but rather that the event handler isn't called at all.